# Teamcity save configuration params of last run

Tags: teamcity

I am using teamcity version 2020.2.2 (build 85899). I have few configuration parameters that I need to provide before start build. When I did it and would like to run another one build I'd like to have those params from last run saved in prompt. I lost it after update teamcity, is it possible to turn it on back?